# Great animation engines for Javascript? - Javascript/Animations

Tags: html, animation, javascript, tween

**I'm trying to implement a timeline based animation, where animations will be able to be:**

- paused
- resumed
- fast forwarded
- slowed down
- reversed
- ...

Are there any animation/tweening engines for Javascript that could be used for such purpose? Or that would be highly recommended?

---

Hwlp would be great, especially as this really interests me! =)

Comment: JQuery and others have general purpose animation engines, but if you need a perfomance and memory stable engine write your own in pure javascript. For the features you mention, it's not hard. A queue and a timer wrapped in a 120-line class worked for me in a situation similar to yours. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of these frameworks will <strike>do that for you</strike> (reverse isn't supported by all of them I see):

- jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- $fx: http://fx.inetcat.com/manuals.php
- Scriptaculous: http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/
- Yahoo! UI Library: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/module_anim.html

I prefer jQuery.

Comment: thanks for that, but what about starting an animation from a certain point in time, within the time frame?

Comment: This might give you some idea:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664867/scrolling-a-jquery-animation-backwards-and-forwards

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're still interested, but i'm looking for the same as you (believe me, I'm searching for HOURS and hours), and I don't know if I really found what I was looking for. The closest is **jsAnim** (http://jsanim.com) and it's working ok for now. I made a list of what i've found on the net:

*(Comments are very unparcial and testing was made very quickly. Please take it with tweezers.)*

- **jsAnim:** Syntax is very easy to focus on animation and not on object architecture (see YUI) (which is great... for engineers...). Easing options are not awesome, but nice. Overall, works fine.
- **Scripty2 (former Script.aculo.us):** Not tested for requiring Prototype.
- **moo.fx:** Not tested for requiring Prototype or mootools.
- **YUI 2/3 Animation:** Worked ok, but it's engineer code has a high learning curve for a casual front-end animation.
- **$fx():** Has a very-ultra-small footprint (only 3 KB!). Would be the choice if only had easing.
- **Trident-js:** Seems to have a very powerful timeline and looks great on the demos, but it didn't worked for me at all and it's skinny documentation don't helps much.
- **Animator.js:** Syntax scared me. Also seemed very amateur to me.
- **JSTweener/GX/xAnimation:** Those didn't captured my attention even a little. Seemed very amateur to me.
- **Glimmer GUI for jQuery code generation:** Setup didn't installed on my machine (installer's unknown error).
- **Raphael/Burst Engine/Processing.js/Pixastic/Cake-js:** They are for canvas/vectors. Another kind of (cool)stuff.
- **Spritely:** Also for another kind of things: sprites animation.

So the winner, for now and for my current animation requirements, is **jsAnim**. I also want to give a try to **Scripty2** and **moo.fx** since they seem to be around for some time (both from 2005, Scripty2 is the second version of Script.acoulo.us).

My 2cents. Hope it helps somebody. Now God I want my last 8 hours back!!!

Comment: I didn't realize how awesome jsAnim was. I saw that you picked jsAnim over libraries on the list I had picked over jsAnim. So I checked it out again and dang it is great. The manager options is great

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're looking for exists, you should write it yourself.

Also I think Adobe is coming out with a set of tools for JS/HTML/CSS animations, you can check their presentation at Google IO.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Yahoo UI:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/

Look at Animation section.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at jQuery animate at

http://www.visualjquery.com/

in the search field write "animate" click on item and you will see some examples there.

Comment: jQuery is wonderful, but I find it quite hard to create a timeline based animation which is also flexible enough to be treated as a "movie".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest BetweenJS a cross-browser portage of BetweenAS3 for Javascript, where everything u asked for is implemented and ready to use
http://github.com/sazaam/BetweenJS/

Answer (score 0):

For a complete feature set, check out [KUTE.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js). It features transform, box model properties, scroll, presentation attributes, SVG morph, SVG draw, tween collections, pause and a ton of easing functions.